# Series Expansion of an Exponential with a Trig Function in the Exponent

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Can anyone get a general expression for

$$e^{a\cos x}$$

in terms of an infinite sum? I'm having trouble with a general form in terms of $n$ for the coefficients...

Alex

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+of+e%5E%28a+cos%28x%29%29%2Cx

Comment: Am I able to use: $e^{acos(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a(cos(x))^{n}}{n!}$ - - I would have thought that the standard exponential expansion wouldn't work when there is a trig function in the exponent...

Comment: Your expression/expansion is correct. It depends on what the instructor/problem is expecting you to do. You need to specify what type of expansion you want. @DannyCheuk gives expansion in terms of $x$ yours is in terms of #\cos x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is of some use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula

**begin quote:**

For any formal power series of the form

$$f(x)=a_1 x+{a_2 \over 2}x^2+{a_3 \over 6}x^3+\cdots+{a_n \over n!}x^n+\cdots$$

we have

$$ \exp f(x)=e^{f(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {b_n \over n!}x^n,$$

where

$$ b_n=\sum_{\pi=\left\{\,S_1,\,\dots,\,S_k\,\right\}} a_{\left|S_1\right|}\cdots a_{\left|S_k\right|},$$

and the index $\pi$ runs through the list of all partitions $\{ S_1,\ldots,S_k\}$ of the set $\{ 1, \ldots , n \}$. (When $k=0$, the product is empty and by definition equals $1$.)

**end of quote**